# write over html number using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, increment

I have a line of html

`<p>Guess #<span id="count">0</span>!</p>`

I need to write a function that will increment the number within the `<span>` tags by 1 each time the `#guessButton` is clicked. A simple `.replaceWith()` method wont work because that doesn't count. I'm assuming I need a for loop.

So far I've got this:

`$("#guessButton").click(function() {
        addOne();
    });`

`addOne()` being the name of the function I will use to increment.

What javascript method can I use in the `addOne()` function to reference a number in the html and make it responsive?

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable `count` and initialize it to zero. Then on every click, increment it and update the span by using the [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method.

```
var count = 0;
$("#guessButton").click(function() {
    count++;
    $('#count').html(count);
});
```

Be sure to add your jquery to the end of the page or wrap it in a [document ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) handler.

Comment: You mean the <script> tag with the link to the minified jquery file?

Comment: No, load jQuery at the head of your page. Load the code in my answer at the end of the page or wrapped in a document ready after jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

another option would be to do it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/c259LrpL/39/

```
<button id="guessButton" type="button">guessButton</button>
<p>Guess #<span id="count">0</span>!</p>


<script>
$('#guessButton').click(function() {
    $('#count').html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why add the parameter of "i" into the function? I don't see where you use it in the code block.

Answer (score 0):

my simpleton answer for your review is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/programndial/eLramyrd/)

```
<p>Guess #<span id="count">0</span>!</p>
<input type="button" id="guessButton" value="Guess" />

$("#guessButton").click(function() {
    var curCount = parseInt($("#count").text(), 10);
    $("#count").text(curCount + 1);
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks...im looking up the parseInt() method and it appears to take a string and turn it into an integer, is that right? Can you explain to me in more detail what is going on in your code? Why the ", 10"?

Comment: parseInt takes a string, and then the integer base that you want your int to be in. so the "10" in the line of code simply tells parseInt that you want a base-10 integer. @ColinAulds

Answer (score 0):

```
function addOne() {
    $('#count').html(
        Number( $('#count').html() ) + 1
    );
}
```